# How to add hyperlink to text in a markdown in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, markdown

I would like to add a hyperlink at the bottom of the screen where the Markdown widget is read.
I tried to include the hyperlink in the markdown file but flutter is not launching it.

Then I tried this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Protective measures'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                  .loadString("assets/docs/protective_measures.md"),
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Markdown(
                    data: snapshot.data,
                    styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet(
                      textAlign: WrapAlignment.start,
                      p: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: isDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                      ),
                      h2: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: isDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                      ),
                      h1: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 25,
                        color: isDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }

                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          InkWell(
            child: Text(
              'My Hyperlink',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.blue,
                decoration: TextDecoration.underline
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () => launch('https://stackoverflow.com'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The result is not really what I wanted. I want a hypertext at the bottom of the screen, just after the Markdown. I also tried with ListView instead of Column but it's not working.

**Any hint ?**

Comment: How do I have a hand cursor for the link on web?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For plugin [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown) you can do like this

```
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

final String _markdownData = "-This is [Google link](https://www.google.com)";

// view
MarkdownBody(
    data: _markdownData,
    onTapLink: (text, url, title){
        launchUrl(Uri.parse(url)); /*For url_launcher 6.1.0 and higher*/
        // launch(url);  /*For url_launcher 6.0.20 and lower*/
    },
)
```

**Update** for flutter_markdown version 0.5.1 or lower:

```
MarkdownBody(
    data: _markdownData,
    onTapLink: (url) {
        launch(url);
    },
)
```

Comment: added syntax update to go with current version of flutter_markdown

Comment: As of, at least, flutter_markdown 0.5.2, the TapLinkCallback returns 3 arguments, so you need to do `onTapLink: (text, url, title) => launch(url),`

Comment: thanks, kindly guide if you know, how to scroll to the same page with #someid link

Comment: For last flutter/dart version, launch function does not accept a null argument.
Use: `launch(url!)`

Comment: `launch` is now depreciated. You can use `launchUrl` instead, and parse the `url` from the `onTapLink` function using `Uri.parse(url)`

Answer (score 2):

I got it. The `Markdown()` widget has a `onTapLink` method and I just need to do:

```
onTapLink(url){
  launch(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to do a null reference check to:

```
MarkdownBody(
    data: privacyPolicy._privacyPolicy,
    onTapLink: (text, url, title){
    launch(url!);
    },
```

Expanding upon the code written by: Azamat Mirvosiqov